# How to prevent automatic registration of an ATL project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, com, atl

I created an ATL C++ project in Visual Studio 2008 that is built as an exe out-of-process COM server. I want to disable its registration upon the build in VS. I thought I did so by unchecking the following option:

[image]

but it still gets registered automatically during the build.

Is there any way to stop it?

Comment: Check under `Build Events > Post-Build Event`